# pandas .loc stops working when imbedded in loop

Tags: python, pandas

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

CSV_output_df = pd.read_csv('output/DEMO_CSV.csv', index_col=None)
payload = {}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic ***********************************************************'
}

for index, row in CSV_output_df.iterrows():
    Package_label = CSV_output_df.loc[index, "Package Id"]
    licenseNumber = CSV_output_df.loc[index, "licenseNumber"]
    Package_label = str(Package_label)
    licenseNumber = str(licenseNumber)
    url = ("https://api-mi.metrc.com/packages/v1/" + Package_label + "?licenseNumber=" + licenseNumber)
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    json_data = (response.text.encode('utf8'))
    json_data = str(json_data)
    json_data = (json_data.strip('b'))
    json_data = (json_data.strip("'"))
    json_data = (json_data.strip('{'))
    json_data = (json_data.strip('}'))
    json_data = (json_data.replace('"Item":{', ''))
    json_data = (json_data.split(','))
    json_data_df = pd.DataFrame(json_data)
    Id = json_data_df.loc[0, 0]
    Id = Id.replace('"Id":', '')
    CSV_output_df.loc[index, "api_id"] = Id

for index, row in CSV_output_df.iterrows():
    api_id = CSV_output_df.loc[index, "api_id"]
    licenseNumber = CSV_output_df.loc[index, "licenseNumber"]
    api_id = str(api_id)
    licenseNumber = str(licenseNumber)
    url0 = ("https://api-mi.metrc.com/labtests/v1/results?packageId=" + api_id + "&licenseNumber=" + licenseNumber)
    response0 = requests.request("GET", url0, headers=headers, data=payload)
    json_data0 = (response0.text.encode('utf8'))
    json_data0 = str(json_data0)
    json_data0 = (json_data0.strip('b'))
    json_data0 = (json_data0.strip("'"))
    json_data0 = (json_data0.strip('{'))
    json_data0 = (json_data0.strip('}'))
    json_data0 = (json_data0.strip('['))
    json_data0 = (json_data0.strip(']'))
    json_data0 = (json_data0.split(','))
    json_data_df0 = pd.DataFrame(json_data0)
    data_point = (json_data_df0.loc[1187, 0])
```

Python noobie here and 1st-time poster. So the issue is, below command not working in my for loop but is working as a standalone command.

```
data_point = (json_data_df0.loc[1187, 0])
```

The traceback log is telling me

> ValueError: 1187 is not in range

but there are 1326 rows in `json_data_df0` and all values except `0, 0` do not work in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are supposed to use `.iloc` if you want to access the columns/rows using integer. `.loc` is for accessing columns/rows using the label.

For your reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: When I use `.iloc`, I get an error as well. `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`

Comment: Can you try to check the dimensionality of dataframe using df.shape? It is strange as the error tells that it is out of bounds and you mentioned that there are 1326 rows.

Comment: df.shape returns 1326 x 1

Comment: maybe creating json_data_df0 inside the loop can be problem. I am not sure, but for every row, you are creating new dataset.